# How can I view request log in API gateway v2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS API Gateway v2 for http endpoints. I have enabled request access log. In cloudwatch log group, I can see the log as below:

```
{
    "requestId": "LbVeJg6aywMEJBg=",
    "ip": "123.208.189.86",
    "requestTime": "23/Apr/2020:06:30:12 +0000",
    "httpMethod": "GET",
    "routeKey": "GET /signup",
    "status": "200",
    "protocol": "HTTP/1.1",
    "responseLength": "20"
}
```

it doesn't include parameters on the URL. How can I view the full request RULs and request payload in log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To give you a brief summary, there are two types of logging - access and execution logs for v1 Amazon REST APIs. With execution logs, you could check what was received in the request to the API and what response was sent out.

However with V2 HTTP APIs, execution logging feature is not available. It's mostly because HTTP APIs support only *proxy integrations* (no request and response transformation). Whatever request the client sends (params, headers etc.) should be checked at the backend integration (Lambda or HTTP) and removing the need for these logs at API level. If you are using Lambda, just print out event data and you should see what params were passed by the client invoking the API.